# Comparing tables in MySQL and adding a yes/no response

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Can someone help me tweak my SQL to get the desired result. I have a table of users, a table of cases, and a relationship table for users attached to cases.

**Users Table - users**

```
+----+-------+--------+
| id | first |  last  |
+----+-------+--------+
|  1 | Joe   | Bloggs |
|  2 | John  | Doe    |
|  3 | Jane  | Doe    |
|  4 | Dave  | Smith  |
+----+-------+--------+
```

**Case Table - cases**

```
+----+--------+------+
| id |  Case  | Code |
+----+--------+------+
|  1 | Case 1 | C1   |
|  2 | Case 2 | C2   |
|  3 | Case 3 | C3   |
+----+--------+------+
```

**Case Users Table - case_users**

```
+----+---------+---------+
| id | case_id | user_id |
+----+---------+---------+
|  1 |       1 |       1 |
|  2 |       1 |       2 |
|  3 |       2 |       4 |
|  4 |       3 |       1 |
|  5 |       1 |       4 |
+----+---------+---------+
```

I want to query the database to return me a full list of users and return a yes or no if they are linked to case 1 and then case 2 case 3 etc.

The SQL I've got so far (selecting for Case ID 1) returns all users but is assigning 'no' to everyone:

```
SELECT
    users.first,
    users.last,
    CASE WHEN case_users.case_id IS NULL THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END AS 'yes/no'
FROM
    users
        LEFT OUTER JOIN case_users ON case_users.case_id = 1
```

My actual result is:

```
+-------+--------+--------+
| First |  Last  | Yes/No |
+-------+--------+--------+
| Joe   | Bloggs | Y      |
| John  | Doe    | Y      |
| Jane  | Doe    | Y      |
| Dave  | Smith  | Y      |
+-------+--------+--------+
```

My desired result should be:

```
+-------+--------+--------+
| First |  Last  | Yes/No |
+-------+--------+--------+
| Joe   | Bloggs | Y      |
| John  | Doe    | Y      |
| Jane  | Doe    | N      |
| Dave  | Smith  | Y      |
+-------+--------+--------+
```

Can someone help me as I can't get the desired result?

Comment: Try the opposite, `...WHEN case_users.case_id IS NOT NULL THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N'...`

Comment: When you joining tables, it's usual to express some sort of relationship between them. For further help, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: thanks jarth, I tried that and it just rendered everyone as N so i need to rethink the logic somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the join condition from users to case_users:

```
SELECT
        users.first,
        users.last,
    CASE WHEN case_users.case_id IS NULL THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END AS 'yes/no'
FROM
    users
        LEFT OUTER JOIN case_users ON users.id = case_users.user_id AND case_users.case_id = 1
```

Comment: thanks Chris that fixed it will remember that as I thought the case created the join but thank you for your help I understand the logic now

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one.

```
SELECT u.first, u.last, IF(cu.case_id,'Y','N') AS CASE_1 FROM users u
LEFT JOIN case_users cu ON u.id = cu.user_id AND cu.case_id = 1
```

Can use `IF(cu.case_id,'Y','N')`condition also instead of `CASE`

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT u.*
      , CASE WHEN cu.case_id IS NULL THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END linked 
   FROM users u 
   JOIN cases c 
   LEFT 
   JOIN case_users cu 
     ON cu.user_id = u.id 
    AND cu.case_id = c.id 
  WHERE c.id = 1;
```